# Robolectric custom shadow writing

Tags: android, robolectric

Hi i have written a class for robolectric 2.3 project as follows

```
@Implements(Bitmap.class)
public class MyShadowBitmap extends ShadowBitmap {

    public MyShadowBitmap() {
       // can also be some other config value
        setConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
}
```

my question is how to write CustomTestRunner class which will extends RobolectricTestRunner and how i will use MyShadowBitmap  for unit testing in robolectric , Please help.

Comment: Have you resolved this? If so, please choose an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Robolectric 2.3, and be able to use custom shadows using the @Config annotation of Robolectric.

Here is what I have:

```
       // ShadowLog class, to print android.util.Log to the console when running tests
       @Implements(Log.class)
       public class ShadowLog {
            @Implementation
            public static void d(String tag, String msg) {
                print(tag, "D", msg, null);
            }
            // other implementation
            private static void print(String tag, String level, String msg, Throwable throwable) {
                System.out.printf("%s(%s): %s. %s\n", tag, level, msg, (null == throwable ? "" : throwable));
            }
       }

       // Test class
       @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
       @Config(shadows = {ShadowLog.class})
       public class MyTest {
           private static final String TAG = MyTest.class.getSimpleName();

           @Test
           public void testLog {
               Log.d(TAG, "debug log");
               Log.i(TAG, "info log");
               Log.w(TAG, "warning log");
               Log.e(TAG, "error log");
           }
       }
```

And this is what I have in the console:

`MyTest(D): debug log. 
    MyTest(I): info log. 
    MyTest(W): warning log. 
    MyTest(E): error log.`

Note: you can also apply the @Config to individual test cases instead of the whole class.